# Is the weak* limit of Girsanov measures also a Girsanov measure?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $\mu_0$ be the standard Wiener measure on $C[0,T]$. Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of measures with $\mu_n\ll \mu_0$ for all $n$ and so that the weak$^\ast$ limit of $\mu_n$ exists, call it $\mu$. Is it true that $\mu \ll \mu_0$?

I know for general measures this is not true. For example we can have a Gaussian with variance $\varepsilon$ and send $\varepsilon \to 0$.

But what about for Girsanov measures?

Comment: What's your definition of a Girsanov measure?  Just that it should be absolutely continuous to Wiener measure (definitely not sufficient for your conclusion), or that it should be the shift of $\mu_0$ by a drift, or what?

Comment: @NateEldredge My definition is that $\mu\ll \mu_0$, which by Girsanov means that there is a progressively measurable $F(t)$ with a.s. $W^{1,2}$ paths so that $B(t)-F(t)$ is a Brownian motion under $\mu$.

Comment: What about taking processes with stronger and stronger drift toward zero?  E.g. $\mu_n$ is the law of $X_t$ which solves $dX_t = -n X_t \,dt + dB_t$?  Shouldn't that converge weakly to a point mass at 0?

Comment: @NateEldredge Is the law of $X_t$ absolutely continuous wrt $\mu_0$ for finite $n$? It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133691/can-i-apply-the-girsanov-theorem-to-an-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge of course, thank you.

Comment: One should also be able to create a more "primitive" example just by taking a sequence of continuous densities that are "bumps" with most of their mass near 0.  Takes a little care if you want the density positive everywhere, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sure. That makes sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes as wrong as can be and has nothing to do with any property of Wiener measure.

**Theorem:** Let $X$ be a separable metric space and $\nu$ a measure on $X$. The set of measures absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$ is dense in the space of measures supported on the support of $\nu$ in the topology of weak convergence of measures.

Proof: Assume without loss of generality that the support of $\mu$ is all of $X$. It is known that the set of measures with finite support is dense, so it suffices to approximate such measures. So let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $X$ with finite support $S$. By the definition of the topology of weak convergence, it suffices to show that there exists for every finite family $\mathcal{G}$ of bounded continuous functions on $X$ and every $\epsilon>0$ some measure $\tau$ on $X$ absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$ such that
$$\bigg|\int g~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\tau\bigg|<\epsilon$$
for all $g\in\mathcal{G}$. For each $s\in S$, let $V_s$ be an open neighborhood on which each $g\in\mathcal{G}$ varies by less than $\epsilon/\# S$. We can and do choose the $V_s$ to be disjoint. Since $\nu$ has full support, we have $\nu(V_s)>0$ for all $s\in S$. Define a measurable function $h:X\to\mathbb{R}$ by letting $h(x)=\mu(s)/\nu(V_s)$ for $x\in V_s$ and $h(x)=0$ if $x$ is in no $V_s$. Let $\tau$ be the measure that has Radon-Nikodym derivative $h$ with respect to $\nu$. Take any $g\in\mathcal{G}$. Then,
$$\bigg|\int g~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\tau\bigg|=\bigg|\int g~\mathrm d\mu-\int hg~\mathrm d\nu\bigg|$$
$$=\bigg| \sum_{s\in S}\bigg(g(s)\mu(s)-\int_{V_s}hg~\mathrm d\nu\bigg)\bigg|$$
$$\leq \sum_{s\in S}\bigg|\bigg(g(s)\mu(s)-\int_{V_s}hg~\mathrm d\nu\bigg)\bigg|$$
$$<\sum_{s\in S} \mu(s)\epsilon/\# S=\epsilon.$$